# Select specific date from datetime field in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have the following records in a table, column 3 is a Datetime type in sqlite.

```
sqlite> .schema candlestick
CREATE TABLE "Candlestick" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "timeframe" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" DATETIME NOT NULL,
  "open" DECIMAL(12, 6) NOT NULL,
  "high" DECIMAL(12, 6) NOT NULL,
  "low" DECIMAL(12, 6) NOT NULL,
  "close" DECIMAL(12, 6) NOT NULL,
  "volume" DECIMAL(12, 6) NOT NULL
);

sqlite> select * from candlestick limit 10;
3668401|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:02:00+01:00|6183|6183|6183|6183|1
3668402|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:03:00+01:00|6180.5|6183|6180.5|6181|133
3668403|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:04:00+01:00|6181.5|6187.5|6181.5|6187.5|55
3668404|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:05:00+01:00|6186|6186|6184.5|6185|166
3668405|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:06:00+01:00|6182|6184.5|6180.5|6181|31
3668406|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:07:00+01:00|6181|6181|6175.5|6176|62
3668407|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:10:00+01:00|6174.5|6174.5|6174.5|6174.5|2
3668408|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:11:00+01:00|6176.5|6177|6176|6177|7
3668409|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:13:00+01:00|6174|6174|6174|6174|23
3668410|Europe/Berlin|1999-12-14 08:15:00+01:00|6174|6174|6173|6173|133
```

How would I select a given date (say `1999-12-15`) from all registers? I.E. all registers that belong to that day, no matter what time they have.

Comment: What is a register? Also please provide the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to use inequalities:

```
where timestamp >= '1999-12-15' and
      timestamp < '1999-12-16'
```

This formulation allows SQLite to use indexes to retrieve the value -- if an appropriate index is available.

SQLite also has a `date()` function (which is really `strftime()` the basis of all SQLite date/time functions).  So you can also write:

```
where date(timestamp) = '1999-12-15'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `"timestamp"` column's data type is actually `TEXT` in **SQLite**, 
so you can use [substr()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) function to extract only the date part:

```
select * from candlestick
where substr(timestamp, 1, 10) = '1999-12-15'
```

You can get the same result with the [like](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) operator:

```
select * from candlestick
where timestamp like '1999-12-15%'
```

See this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for more info on **SQLite** data types